# What exactly is compiled in precompiled headers?

Tags: precompiled-headers

From what I know, headers used properly should only contain function prototypes and defines, which are not compiled. Only the global variables will be compiled. So why bothering with precompiled headers when there's almost nothing to compile ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: It's a misnomer, they should have been called "pre-parsed" instead. In most implementations it's just a serialised AST.

Answer (score 0):

The point of precompiled headers is to speed up compilation.
And yes, everything is compiled, even if it does not generate
assembly output, it still generates internal compiler symbols.